# parsing part of the table for data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a self-project to scrape data online using BeautifulSoup and Python, and I think historical stocks data would be a good one for me to practice.  I looked at the source code [here](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL) to analyze how I can use BeautifulSoup's select() or findall() to parse part of the data from the table.  Here is the code I use, but it parsed things other than the table.

`soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll( 'td', {'class':'yfnc_tabledata1'} )
print table`

My Question: How to I parse only the 2 rows showing the 2 days of data from the table?

Here is the table that has 2 days of the historical data:

```
<table class="yfnc_datamodoutline1" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tr valign="top">
<td>

<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="16%">Date</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="12%">Open</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="12%">High</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="12%">Low</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="12%">close</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="16%">Volume</th>
<th scope="col" class="yfnc_tablehead1" align="right" width="15%">Adj Close*</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">12 Aug 2016</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.78</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.44</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.78</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.18</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">18,612,300</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">11 Aug 2016</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.52</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.93</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.85</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.93</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">27,484,500</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.93</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" colspan="7" align="center">
* <small>Close price adjusted for dividends and splits.</small>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I only need the specific 2 rows of data from above:

```
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">12 Aug 2016</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.78</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.44</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.78</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.18</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">18,612,300</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap align="right">11 Aug 2016</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.52</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">108.93</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.85</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.93</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">27,484,500</td>
<td class="yfnc_tabledata1" align="right">107.93</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I don't see how the nesting level makes a difference. After you've used `find()` to get the table, you can access its children without having to worry about nesting. What's your actual problem? Are you having trouble _finding_ the table?

Comment: I not only parse the table, but also other parts the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can  select the all the rows from the nested table inside the *yfnc_datamodoutline1* table and index the first two:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table_rows = soup.select("table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table tr + tr")
row1, row2 =  table_rows[0:2]

print(row1)
print(row2)
```

Which would give you:

```
<tr>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap="">12 Aug 2016</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">107.78</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">108.44</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">107.78</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">108.18</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">18,612,300</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">108.18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1" nowrap="">11 Aug 2016</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">108.52</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">108.93</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">107.85</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">107.93</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">27,484,500</td>
<td align="right" class="yfnc_tabledata1">107.93</td>
</tr>
```

To get the td data just extract the text from each td:

```
print([td.text for td in row1.find_all("td")])
print([td.text for td in row2.find_all("td")])
```

Which would give you:

```
[u'12 Aug 2016', u'107.78', u'108.44', u'107.78', u'108.18', u'18,612,300', u'108.18']
[u'11 Aug 2016', u'108.52', u'108.93', u'107.85', u'107.93', u'27,484,500', u'107.93']
```

*table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table tr + tr* selects all the rows inside the inner table skipping the first which is the header row.

Comment: table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table tr + tr parses 2 rows.  What to do when there are different numbers of rows of data to parse?

Comment: @LEDFantom, I don't understand what you `mean.table.yfnc_datamodoutline1 table tr + tr parses` parses all rows not including the first